# What is the legality of growing San Pedro cacti in Florida?

Tags: cactus, succulents

Clusters of columnar cacti like the San Pedro (Echinopsis pachanoi) are very appealing to me. I want to grow it all around my house. I am aware however that this is considered to be a hallucinogenic drug when consumed, so I am curious as to the legality of growing it in Florida (with no intentions of consumption). I would hate for a police brigade to surround my house in some years when I have a front lawn full of psychoactive cacti hiding in plain sight.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the law are out of scope

Comment: Well there is no Legal Stack Overflow so the next best subject would be Gardening & Landscaping.

Comment: Each Stack Exchange forum can only address questions in the members field of expertise.  I'm not a lawyer and even if I was I should not practice law on an internet forum.

Comment: @PJS1987: You're right, there is no legal SE. ***Yet***. There is, however, a proposal on area51, which you can vote for or commit to; http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law

Comment: There is a legal [site](https://law.stackexchange.com/) but you have to pretend its not real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have changed name now, so its Trichocereus pachanoi, and there is someone on a web forum growing it outdoors in Florida - but you should maybe check with whatever passes for your Council or Local Authority to see if planting lots of them is a problem. They're not exactly like marijuana, after all...